# HTML phone number can't be sent to device with Google

Tags: html

So I used this link : `<a href="tel:123-456-7890">phone number</a>`
to add a calling function on a page.
When I click it on **mobile**, it opens my calls app and is ready to call the number
But on **desktop browser** , when I try the call function of Google "*Make call from:*" it tries to send the number and fails saying "*Cant share number*".

Comment: When you say "Google", do you mean "Google Chrome" or some other product? A `tel:` link needs to have a registered handler to work on desktops. I'm not familiar with anything saying "Make call from".

Comment: I know that on mac when you click these `tel:` links in chrome you have to have facetime set up as your calling client for you to be able to make a call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so problem solved. Just a day after the phone num send works without changing anything myself. I guess it had something to do with Google?